# Way to get number of digits from a long using Modulos

Tags: java

My ta told me that if i want to count the length of a long variable I can create a method using modulos. From what I understood he was saying that i need to keep using modulos until the long is 0. Here's what I'm thinking right now, but i'm pretty lost.

```
public static int inputSize(long cc_num)
{
  int count = 0;
  while( cc_num > 0) 
    {
     count += 1;
     cc_num = cc_num % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your ta probably meant `/` division, not `%` modulo (also your method needs to `return` something).

Comment: `public static boolean validSize(long cc_num)
   {
       int count = 0;
       boolean valid = false;
       
       //checks size of long
       while(cc_num > 0)
       {
           count++;
           cc_num = cc_num / 10;
        }
        
        //checks if length of long is correct
       if (count == 15 || count == 16)
            valid = true;
       
       return valid; 
   }`

Would this method be correct then @Pshemo?

Comment: ^sorry im not sure how to format comments

Comment: You can't properly format code in comments that is why try to avoid posting code as comment (especially if it has `//comment` sections). Anyway code you provided doesn't seem to return length of long and I am not sure what is its purpose. Do you want to make sure that length is `15` or `16`? If so I would probably create two methods, first one which you posted, and second like `public static validSize(long cc_num){int size = inputSize(cc_num); return size==15||size==16;}`.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that you want the number of digits of the base 10 representation.

Comment: @MaxZoom - if you are going to edit/approve an edit somebody else's question, please don't alter the code to the extent that it fundamentally changes (or in that case, answers) the question. Also - you completely messed up the formatting.

Comment: @ziggy - if that was your edit that MaxZoom was approving then apologies but I rolled it back as it would be more appropriate to add the edit to the end of the question rather than changing the fundamental nature of your question.

Comment: @ziggy You newer version is pretty close to be the right solution. I will list the code below to add small corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with minor changes:

```
public static boolean validSize(long cc_num) {
  int count = 0;
  if (cc_num < 0)  cc_num *= -1; // fix negative number

  while (cc_num > 0) {
    count++;
    cc_num = cc_num / 10;
  }

  //checks if length of long is correct
  return count == 15 || count == 16;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's almost correct.
Just replace the % operator with / operator:
cc_num /= 10;
That should work :)

Comment: If `cc_num` is a negative number, it returns always zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of possible comparisons:

```
public static int inputSize(long cc_num)
{
    if(cc_num < 0)  // check for negative numbers
       cc_num = -cc_num;
    int count = 1;
    if(cc_num >= 10000000000000000L)
    {
        count += 16;
        cc_num /= 10000000000000000L;
    }
    if(cc_num >= 100000000)
    {
        count += 8;
        cc_num /= 100000000;
    }
    if(cc_num >= 10000)
    {
        count += 4;
        cc_num /= 10000;
    }
    if(cc_num >= 100)
    {
        count += 2;
        cc_num /= 100;
    }
    if(cc_num >= 10)
    {
        count ++;
    }
    return count;
}
```